# Scala: type arguments do not conform to class type parameter bounds

Tags: scala

My code

```
object TestApp extends App {   
  class A[T <: Ordered[T]] {
    def check(f: T, s: T) = f > s
  }    
  object A {
    def apply[T] = new A[T]
  }   
  A[String].check("ab", "aa")    
}
```

throws an exception:

```
Error:(13, 9) type arguments [T] do not conform to class A's type parameter bounds [T <: Ordered[T]]
    def apply[T] = new A[T]
        ^
```

But I don't understand why. For me, it seems ok. I have a class with type variable bounded with Ordered. In companion object, I'm trying to create an instance of A. But I'm not sure if my companion object has an access to the type variable of class A.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String` doesn't extend `Ordered` in scala, it's just an alias for `java.lang.String`, plus your `apply` doesn't conform to the context bound you have in `A` (you accept any `T` there), you can work around requiring an implicit `Ordering` for that type:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class A[T](implicit ord: Ordering[T]) {
  def check(f: T, s: T) = ord.gt(f, s)
}

object A {
  def apply[T](implicit ord: Ordering[T]) = new A[T]
}

A[String].check("ab", "aa")

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class A
defined object A
res0: Boolean = true
```

To show you that implicit conversions don't work for context bounds I made a small example:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait A
case class AA() extends A
case class CC()
implicit def conv(a: CC): A = AA() 

def f[T <: A](x: T): T = x
f(CC())

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:23: error: inferred type arguments [CC] do not conform to method f's type parameter bounds [T <: A]
     f(CC())
```

As you can see the implicit I defined wasn't applied to `CC` to match the context bound.

Comment: But `String` has implicit converter to `StringOps` which does extend `Ordered` trait.

Comment: `implicit def augmentString(x: String): StringOps = new StringOps(x)` in `Predef`

Comment: I can write `class B { def check(f: String, s: String) = f > s }` and it works.

Comment: @Finkelson Agreed, and in fact if you do something like `val p: StringOps = "123"` the implicit conversion from `String` to `StringOps` kicks in, but it won't to satisfy a context bound.

Comment: @Finkelson I added a small example showing that implicits don't kick in to satisfy context bounds.